# how to disable toolbar from Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, pdf, iframe

I want to show PDF file in Iframe so I user `pdf.js`  for this.

```html
<iframe src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html" 
class="iframe-view" width="100%" height="300" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

Now its working fine for me.

But I want to disable toolbar now from the Iframe.

I tried to remove `toolbar div` with the help of js

But I didn't get that this toolbar div with this code  `$(".toolbar")`

Can anyone know how can I disable this?

Thank you.

Comment: Browser toolbar of PDF toolbar? The latter is on the URL and not the iframe - but I never heard of an iFrame with toolbars

Comment: you can check pdf.js on github

Comment: No I cannot. YOU can create a [mcve] and show an image of what you are trying to do.

Comment: The iframe content is from another origin (host or port number) you will get cross origin errors as I see in a comment you had. . PDF.js does not seem to support that: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/6087

Comment: Seems you can just edit viewer.html and remove the controls or add `<style>#controls { display:none }</style>` to after the css file in viewer

Comment: i don't have this file in my code. it's plugin's file

Comment: But the idea is you install it an not run from GitHub

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to manipulate the content of the IFrame you could try to use:

```
$("#myiframe").contents().find(".toolbar");
```

But I dont know if you can hide the tollbar using this method.

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.  GETTING THIS ERROR IN CONSOLE